# incompatible shape on image segmentation task

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, computer-vision, image-segmentation

I'm trying to achieve an image segmentation task. I'm using U-Net defined in [Python library with Neural Networks for Image Segmentation](https://github.com/qubvel/segmentation_models) but when I try to run `model.fit` i get this error:

> WARNING: tensorflow:Model was constructed with shape (None, None, None,
> 3) for input KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, None, None,
> 3), dtype=tf.float32, name='data'), name='data', description="created
> by layer 'data'"), but it was called on an input with incompatible
> shape (None, 256, 256, 1).
>
> [...]
>
> Input 0 of layer "bn_data" is incompatible with the layer: expected axis 3 of input shape > to have value 3, but received input with shape (None, 256, 256, 1)

I think I understand the problem (but I have no idea on how to fix it) beacuse If i debug my code I can see that my shape is, as mentioned in the error, (2332, 256, 256, 1) for both images and masks.

Another thing that doesn't make sense to me is that from the model summary I see too many 'None' that I think should not be there. Could someone give me some explanation?

```
Model: "model_1"
Layer (type)                   Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
data (InputLayer)              [(None, None, None,  0           []                               
                               3)]  
bn_data (BatchNormalization)   (None, None, None,   9           ['data[0][0]']  
                               3) 
zero_padding2d (ZeroPadding2D) (None, None, None,   0           ['bn_data[0][0]']                
                                3) 
conv0 (Conv2D)                 (None, None, None,   9408        ['zero_padding2d[0][0]']         
                               64)  
.
.
.
Total params: 24,456,154
Trainable params: 24,438,804
Non-trainable params: 17,350
```

This is the code I wrote:

```
# resize img to 256
SIZE = 256
backbone = 'resnet34'

# defining empty lists, so we can capture all images and convert them into numpy array
image_dataset = []
mask_dataset = []

# storing images and masks code here, skip code 
#img
for (..)
#masks
for (..)

image_dataset = np.expand_dims(normalize(np.array(image_dataset), axis=1), 3)

mask_dataset = np.expand_dims((np.array(mask_dataset)), 3)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(image_dataset, mask_dataset,test_size=0.10, random_state=0)

# define model
model = sm.Unet(backbone, encoder_weights='imagenet')
model.compile('Adam', loss=sm.losses.binary_crossentropy, metrics=[sm.metrics.iou_score], )

print(model.summary())

model.fit(
   x=X_train, y=y_train,
   batch_size=16,
   epochs=10,
   verbose=1,
   validation_data=(X_test, y_test),
   shuffle=False
)
```

Note on dataset: image sizes of approximately 230 x 630 pixels

Answer (score 2):

The input and output shape they mentioned on the website

There are many applications but to work with number of calsses activation Fn sigmoids we use " **model = sm.Unet('resnet34', input_shape=(32, 32, 3), classes=3, activation='sigmoid')** " [segmentation U-net](https://github.com/qubvel/segmentation_models)

Try to make it square shape computing sizes, up and downsampling within scopes of its inputs ...

Go along the pixel matching and find your target response.

Sample: Match of input/output logits with input shape and label. It is multiclass input/output because they build with upsampling and downsampling with multiple layers and connected layers.

```
import os
from os.path import exists

import segmentation_models as sm
# Segmentation Models: using `keras` framework.

import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_io as tfio

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Variables
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
OUTPUT_CLASSES = 3
BACKBONE = 'resnet34'
preprocess_input = sm.get_preprocessing(BACKBONE)

PATH = os.path.join('F:\\datasets\\downloads\\Actors\\train\\Pikaploy', '*.tif')
PATH_2 = os.path.join('F:\\datasets\\downloads\\Actors\\train\\Candidt Kibt', '*.tif')
files = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(PATH)
files_2 = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(PATH_2)

list_file = []
list_file_actual = []
list_label = []
list_label_actual = [ 'Pikaploy', 'Pikaploy', 'Pikaploy', 'Pikaploy', 'Pikaploy', 'Candidt Kibt', 'Candidt Kibt', 'Candidt Kibt', 'Candidt Kibt', 'Candidt Kibt' ]
for file in files.take(5):
    image = tf.io.read_file( file )
    image = tfio.experimental.image.decode_tiff(image, index=0)
    list_file_actual.append(image)
    image = tf.image.resize(image, [32,32], method='nearest')
    image = tfio.experimental.color.rgba_to_rgb( image, name="rgba to rgb" )
    list_file.append(image)
    list_label.append(1)
    
for file in files_2.take(5):
    image = tf.io.read_file( file )
    image = tfio.experimental.image.decode_tiff(image, index=0)
    list_file_actual.append(image)
    image = tf.image.resize(image, [32,32], method='nearest')
    image = tfio.experimental.color.rgba_to_rgb( image, name="rgba to rgb" )
    list_file.append(image)
    list_label.append(9)

checkpoint_path = "F:\\models\\checkpoint\\" + os.path.basename(__file__).split('.')[0] + "\\TF_DataSets_01.h5"
checkpoint_dir = os.path.dirname(checkpoint_path)

if not exists(checkpoint_dir) : 
    os.mkdir(checkpoint_dir)
    print("Create directory: " + checkpoint_dir)
    
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: DataSet
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((tf.constant(tf.cast(list_file, dtype=tf.int64), shape=(10, 1, 32, 32, 3), dtype=tf.int64),tf.constant(list_label, shape=(10, 1, 1), dtype=tf.int64)))

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Model Initialize
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
model = sm.Unet('resnet34', input_shape=(32, 32, 3), classes=3, activation='sigmoid')

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Optimizer
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Nadam( learning_rate=0.0001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=1e-07, name='Nadam' )

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Loss Fn
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""                               
lossfn = tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError( reduction=tf.keras.losses.Reduction.AUTO, name='mean_squared_error' )

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Model Summary
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=lossfn, metrics=[ tf.keras.metrics.RootMeanSquaredError( name='root_mean_squared_error' ) ])
model.summary()

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: FileWriter
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
if exists(checkpoint_path) :
    model.load_weights(checkpoint_path)
    print("model load: " + checkpoint_path)
    input("Press Any Key!")

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Training
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
history = model.fit( dataset, epochs=5, steps_per_epoch=1 )
model.save_weights(checkpoint_path)

input("...")
```

Output: Matching of output logits and labels

```
Model: "model_1"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                   Output Shape         Param #     Connected to
==================================================================================================
 data (InputLayer)              [(None, 32, 32, 3)]  0           []

 bn_data (BatchNormalization)   (None, 32, 32, 3)    9           ['data[0][0]']

 zero_padding2d (ZeroPadding2D)  (None, 38, 38, 3)   0           ['bn_data[0][0]']

 conv0 (Conv2D)                 (None, 16, 16, 64)   9408        ['zero_padding2d[0][0]']

 bn0 (BatchNormalization)       (None, 16, 16, 64)   256         ['conv0[0][0]']

 relu0 (Activation)             (None, 16, 16, 64)   0           ['bn0[0][0]']

 zero_padding2d_1 (ZeroPadding2  (None, 18, 18, 64)  0           ['relu0[0][0]']
 D)

 pooling0 (MaxPooling2D)        (None, 8, 8, 64)     0           ['zero_padding2d_1[0][0]']

 stage1_unit1_bn1 (BatchNormali  (None, 8, 8, 64)    256         ['pooling0[0][0]']
 zation)

 stage1_unit1_relu1 (Activation  (None, 8, 8, 64)    0           ['stage1_unit1_bn1[0][0]']
 )

 zero_padding2d_2 (ZeroPadding2  (None, 10, 10, 64)  0           ['stage1_unit1_relu1[0][0]']
 D)

 stage1_unit1_conv1 (Conv2D)    (None, 8, 8, 64)     36864       ['zero_padding2d_2[0][0]']

 stage1_unit1_bn2 (BatchNormali  (None, 8, 8, 64)    256         ['stage1_unit1_conv1[0][0]']
 zation)

 stage1_unit1_relu2 (Activation  (None, 8, 8, 64)    0           ['stage1_unit1_bn2[0][0]']
 )

 zero_padding2d_3 (ZeroPadding2  (None, 10, 10, 64)  0           ['stage1_unit1_relu2[0][0]']
 D)

 stage1_unit1_conv2 (Conv2D)    (None, 8, 8, 64)     36864       ['zero_padding2d_3[0][0]']

 stage1_unit1_sc (Conv2D)       (None, 8, 8, 64)     4096        ['stage1_unit1_relu1[0][0]']

 add (Add)                      (None, 8, 8, 64)     0           ['stage1_unit1_conv2[0][0]',
                                                                  'stage1_unit1_sc[0][0]']

 stage1_unit2_bn1 (BatchNormali  (None, 8, 8, 64)    256         ['add[0][0]']
 zation)

 stage1_unit2_relu1 (Activation  (None, 8, 8, 64)    0           ['stage1_unit2_bn1[0][0]']
 )

 zero_padding2d_4 (ZeroPadding2  (None, 10, 10, 64)  0           ['stage1_unit2_relu1[0][0]']
 D)

 stage1_unit2_conv1 (Conv2D)    (None, 8, 8, 64)     36864       ['zero_padding2d_4[0][0]']

 stage1_unit2_bn2 (BatchNormali  (None, 8, 8, 64)    256         ['stage1_unit2_conv1[0][0]']
 zation)

 stage1_unit2_relu2 (Activation  (None, 8, 8, 64)    0           ['stage1_unit2_bn2[0][0]']
 )

 zero_padding2d_5 (ZeroPadding2  (None, 10, 10, 64)  0           ['stage1_unit2_relu2[0][0]']
 D)

 stage1_unit2_conv2 (Conv2D)    (None, 8, 8, 64)     36864       ['zero_padding2d_5[0][0]']

 add_1 (Add)                    (None, 8, 8, 64)     0           ['stage1_unit2_conv2[0][0]',
                                                                  'add[0][0]']

 stage1_unit3_bn1 (BatchNormali  (None, 8, 8, 64)    256         ['add_1[0][0]']
 zation)

 stage1_unit3_relu1 (Activation  (None, 8, 8, 64)    0           ['stage1_unit3_bn1[0][0]']
 )

 zero_padding2d_6 (ZeroPadding2  (None, 10, 10, 64)  0           ['stage1_unit3_relu1[0][0]']
 D)

 stage1_unit3_conv1 (Conv2D)    (None, 8, 8, 64)     36864       ['zero_padding2d_6[0][0]']

 stage1_unit3_bn2 (BatchNormali  (None, 8, 8, 64)    256         ['stage1_unit3_conv1[0][0]']
 zation)

 stage1_unit3_relu2 (Activation  (None, 8, 8, 64)    0           ['stage1_unit3_bn2[0][0]']
 )

 zero_padding2d_7 (ZeroPadding2  (None, 10, 10, 64)  0           ['stage1_unit3_relu2[0][0]']
 D)

 stage1_unit3_conv2 (Conv2D)    (None, 8, 8, 64)     36864       ['zero_padding2d_7[0][0]']

 add_2 (Add)                    (None, 8, 8, 64)     0           ['stage1_unit3_conv2[0][0]',
                                                                  'add_1[0][0]']

 stage2_unit1_bn1 (BatchNormali  (None, 8, 8, 64)    256         ['add_2[0][0]']
 zation)

 stage2_unit1_relu1 (Activation  (None, 8, 8, 64)    0           ['stage2_unit1_bn1[0][0]']
 )

 zero_padding2d_8 (ZeroPadding2  (None, 10, 10, 64)  0           ['stage2_unit1_relu1[0][0]']
 D)

 stage2_unit1_conv1 (Conv2D)    (None, 4, 4, 128)    73728       ['zero_padding2d_8[0][0]']

 stage2_unit1_bn2 (BatchNormali  (None, 4, 4, 128)   512         ['stage2_unit1_conv1[0][0]']
 zation)

 stage2_unit1_relu2 (Activation  (None, 4, 4, 128)   0           ['stage2_unit1_bn2[0][0]']
 )

 zero_padding2d_9 (ZeroPadding2  (None, 6, 6, 128)   0           ['stage2_unit1_relu2[0][0]']
 D)

 stage2_unit1_conv2 (Conv2D)    (None, 4, 4, 128)    147456      ['zero_padding2d_9[0][0]']

 stage2_unit1_sc (Conv2D)       (None, 4, 4, 128)    8192        ['stage2_unit1_relu1[0][0]']

 add_3 (Add)                    (None, 4, 4, 128)    0           ['stage2_unit1_conv2[0][0]',
                                                                  'stage2_unit1_sc[0][0]']

 stage2_unit2_bn1 (BatchNormali  (None, 4, 4, 128)   512         ['add_3[0][0]']
 zation)

 stage2_unit2_relu1 (Activation  (None, 4, 4, 128)   0           ['stage2_unit2_bn1[0][0]']
 )

 zero_padding2d_10 (ZeroPadding  (None, 6, 6, 128)   0           ['stage2_unit2_relu1[0][0]']
 2D)

 stage2_unit2_conv1 (Conv2D)    (None, 4, 4, 128)    147456      ['zero_padding2d_10[0][0]']

 stage2_unit2_bn2 (BatchNormali  (None, 4, 4, 128)   512         ['stage2_unit2_conv1[0][0]']
 zation)

 stage2_unit2_relu2 (Activation  (None, 4, 4, 128)   0           ['stage2_unit2_bn2[0][0]']
 )

 zero_padding2d_11 (ZeroPadding  (None, 6, 6, 128)   0           ['stage2_unit2_relu2[0][0]']
 2D)

 stage2_unit2_conv2 (Conv2D)    (None, 4, 4, 128)    147456      ['zero_padding2d_11[0][0]']

 add_4 (Add)                    (None, 4, 4, 128)    0           ['stage2_unit2_conv2[0][0]',
                                                                  'add_3[0][0]']

 stage2_unit3_bn1 (BatchNormali  (None, 4, 4, 128)   512         ['add_4[0][0]']
 zation)

 stage2_unit3_relu1 (Activation  (None, 4, 4, 128)   0           ['stage2_unit3_bn1[0][0]']
 )

 zero_padding2d_12 (ZeroPadding  (None, 6, 6, 128)   0           ['stage2_unit3_relu1[0][0]']
 2D)

 stage2_unit3_conv1 (Conv2D)    (None, 4, 4, 128)    147456      ['zero_padding2d_12[0][0]']

 stage2_unit3_bn2 (BatchNormali  (None, 4, 4, 128)   512         ['stage2_unit3_conv1[0][0]']
 zation)

 stage2_unit3_relu2 (Activation  (None, 4, 4, 128)   0           ['stage2_unit3_bn2[0][0]']
 )

 zero_padding2d_13 (ZeroPadding  (None, 6, 6, 128)   0           ['stage2_unit3_relu2[0][0]']
 2D)

 stage2_unit3_conv2 (Conv2D)    (None, 4, 4, 128)    147456      ['zero_padding2d_13[0][0]']

 add_5 (Add)                    (None, 4, 4, 128)    0           ['stage2_unit3_conv2[0][0]',
                                                                  'add_4[0][0]']

 stage2_unit4_bn1 (BatchNormali  (None, 4, 4, 128)   512         ['add_5[0][0]']
 zation)

 stage2_unit4_relu1 (Activation  (None, 4, 4, 128)   0           ['stage2_unit4_bn1[0][0]']
 )

 zero_padding2d_14 (ZeroPadding  (None, 6, 6, 128)   0           ['stage2_unit4_relu1[0][0]']
 2D)

 stage2_unit4_conv1 (Conv2D)    (None, 4, 4, 128)    147456      ['zero_padding2d_14[0][0]']

 stage2_unit4_bn2 (BatchNormali  (None, 4, 4, 128)   512         ['stage2_unit4_conv1[0][0]']
 zation)

 stage2_unit4_relu2 (Activation  (None, 4, 4, 128)   0           ['stage2_unit4_bn2[0][0]']
 )

 zero_padding2d_15 (ZeroPadding  (None, 6, 6, 128)   0           ['stage2_unit4_relu2[0][0]']
 2D)

 stage2_unit4_conv2 (Conv2D)    (None, 4, 4, 128)    147456      ['zero_padding2d_15[0][0]']

 add_6 (Add)                    (None, 4, 4, 128)    0           ['stage2_unit4_conv2[0][0]',
                                                                  'add_5[0][0]']

 stage3_unit1_bn1 (BatchNormali  (None, 4, 4, 128)   512         ['add_6[0][0]']
 zation)

 stage3_unit1_relu1 (Activation  (None, 4, 4, 128)   0           ['stage3_unit1_bn1[0][0]']
 )

 zero_padding2d_16 (ZeroPadding  (None, 6, 6, 128)   0           ['stage3_unit1_relu1[0][0]']
 2D)

 stage3_unit1_conv1 (Conv2D)    (None, 2, 2, 256)    294912      ['zero_padding2d_16[0][0]']

 stage3_unit1_bn2 (BatchNormali  (None, 2, 2, 256)   1024        ['stage3_unit1_conv1[0][0]']
 zation)

 stage3_unit1_relu2 (Activation  (None, 2, 2, 256)   0           ['stage3_unit1_bn2[0][0]']
 )

 zero_padding2d_17 (ZeroPadding  (None, 4, 4, 256)   0           ['stage3_unit1_relu2[0][0]']
 2D)

 stage3_unit1_conv2 (Conv2D)    (None, 2, 2, 256)    589824      ['zero_padding2d_17[0][0]']

 stage3_unit1_sc (Conv2D)       (None, 2, 2, 256)    32768       ['stage3_unit1_relu1[0][0]']

 add_7 (Add)                    (None, 2, 2, 256)    0           ['stage3_unit1_conv2[0][0]',
                                                                  'stage3_unit1_sc[0][0]']

 stage3_unit2_bn1 (BatchNormali  (None, 2, 2, 256)   1024        ['add_7[0][0]']
 zation)

 stage3_unit2_relu1 (Activation  (None, 2, 2, 256)   0           ['stage3_unit2_bn1[0][0]']
 )

 zero_padding2d_18 (ZeroPadding  (None, 4, 4, 256)   0           ['stage3_unit2_relu1[0][0]']
 2D)

 stage3_unit2_conv1 (Conv2D)    (None, 2, 2, 256)    589824      ['zero_padding2d_18[0][0]']

 stage3_unit2_bn2 (BatchNormali  (None, 2, 2, 256)   1024        ['stage3_unit2_conv1[0][0]']
 zation)

 stage3_unit2_relu2 (Activation  (None, 2, 2, 256)   0           ['stage3_unit2_bn2[0][0]']
 )

 zero_padding2d_19 (ZeroPadding  (None, 4, 4, 256)   0           ['stage3_unit2_relu2[0][0]']
 2D)

 stage3_unit2_conv2 (Conv2D)    (None, 2, 2, 256)    589824      ['zero_padding2d_19[0][0]']

 add_8 (Add)                    (None, 2, 2, 256)    0           ['stage3_unit2_conv2[0][0]',
                                                                  'add_7[0][0]']

 stage3_unit3_bn1 (BatchNormali  (None, 2, 2, 256)   1024        ['add_8[0][0]']
 zation)

 stage3_unit3_relu1 (Activation  (None, 2, 2, 256)   0           ['stage3_unit3_bn1[0][0]']
 )

 zero_padding2d_20 (ZeroPadding  (None, 4, 4, 256)   0           ['stage3_unit3_relu1[0][0]']
 2D)

 stage3_unit3_conv1 (Conv2D)    (None, 2, 2, 256)    589824      ['zero_padding2d_20[0][0]']

 stage3_unit3_bn2 (BatchNormali  (None, 2, 2, 256)   1024        ['stage3_unit3_conv1[0][0]']
 zation)

 stage3_unit3_relu2 (Activation  (None, 2, 2, 256)   0           ['stage3_unit3_bn2[0][0]']
 )

 zero_padding2d_21 (ZeroPadding  (None, 4, 4, 256)   0           ['stage3_unit3_relu2[0][0]']
 2D)

 stage3_unit3_conv2 (Conv2D)    (None, 2, 2, 256)    589824      ['zero_padding2d_21[0][0]']

 add_9 (Add)                    (None, 2, 2, 256)    0           ['stage3_unit3_conv2[0][0]',
                                                                  'add_8[0][0]']

 stage3_unit4_bn1 (BatchNormali  (None, 2, 2, 256)   1024        ['add_9[0][0]']
 zation)

 stage3_unit4_relu1 (Activation  (None, 2, 2, 256)   0           ['stage3_unit4_bn1[0][0]']
 )

 zero_padding2d_22 (ZeroPadding  (None, 4, 4, 256)   0           ['stage3_unit4_relu1[0][0]']
 2D)

 stage3_unit4_conv1 (Conv2D)    (None, 2, 2, 256)    589824      ['zero_padding2d_22[0][0]']

 stage3_unit4_bn2 (BatchNormali  (None, 2, 2, 256)   1024        ['stage3_unit4_conv1[0][0]']
 zation)

 stage3_unit4_relu2 (Activation  (None, 2, 2, 256)   0           ['stage3_unit4_bn2[0][0]']
 )

 zero_padding2d_23 (ZeroPadding  (None, 4, 4, 256)   0           ['stage3_unit4_relu2[0][0]']
 2D)

 stage3_unit4_conv2 (Conv2D)    (None, 2, 2, 256)    589824      ['zero_padding2d_23[0][0]']

 add_10 (Add)                   (None, 2, 2, 256)    0           ['stage3_unit4_conv2[0][0]',
                                                                  'add_9[0][0]']

 stage3_unit5_bn1 (BatchNormali  (None, 2, 2, 256)   1024        ['add_10[0][0]']
 zation)

 stage3_unit5_relu1 (Activation  (None, 2, 2, 256)   0           ['stage3_unit5_bn1[0][0]']
 )

 zero_padding2d_24 (ZeroPadding  (None, 4, 4, 256)   0           ['stage3_unit5_relu1[0][0]']
 2D)

 stage3_unit5_conv1 (Conv2D)    (None, 2, 2, 256)    589824      ['zero_padding2d_24[0][0]']

 stage3_unit5_bn2 (BatchNormali  (None, 2, 2, 256)   1024        ['stage3_unit5_conv1[0][0]']
 zation)

 stage3_unit5_relu2 (Activation  (None, 2, 2, 256)   0           ['stage3_unit5_bn2[0][0]']
 )

 zero_padding2d_25 (ZeroPadding  (None, 4, 4, 256)   0           ['stage3_unit5_relu2[0][0]']
 2D)

 stage3_unit5_conv2 (Conv2D)    (None, 2, 2, 256)    589824      ['zero_padding2d_25[0][0]']

 add_11 (Add)                   (None, 2, 2, 256)    0           ['stage3_unit5_conv2[0][0]',
                                                                  'add_10[0][0]']

 stage3_unit6_bn1 (BatchNormali  (None, 2, 2, 256)   1024        ['add_11[0][0]']
 zation)

 stage3_unit6_relu1 (Activation  (None, 2, 2, 256)   0           ['stage3_unit6_bn1[0][0]']
 )

 zero_padding2d_26 (ZeroPadding  (None, 4, 4, 256)   0           ['stage3_unit6_relu1[0][0]']
 2D)

 stage3_unit6_conv1 (Conv2D)    (None, 2, 2, 256)    589824      ['zero_padding2d_26[0][0]']

 stage3_unit6_bn2 (BatchNormali  (None, 2, 2, 256)   1024        ['stage3_unit6_conv1[0][0]']
 zation)

 stage3_unit6_relu2 (Activation  (None, 2, 2, 256)   0           ['stage3_unit6_bn2[0][0]']
 )

 zero_padding2d_27 (ZeroPadding  (None, 4, 4, 256)   0           ['stage3_unit6_relu2[0][0]']
 2D)

 stage3_unit6_conv2 (Conv2D)    (None, 2, 2, 256)    589824      ['zero_padding2d_27[0][0]']

 add_12 (Add)                   (None, 2, 2, 256)    0           ['stage3_unit6_conv2[0][0]',
                                                                  'add_11[0][0]']

 stage4_unit1_bn1 (BatchNormali  (None, 2, 2, 256)   1024        ['add_12[0][0]']
 zation)

 stage4_unit1_relu1 (Activation  (None, 2, 2, 256)   0           ['stage4_unit1_bn1[0][0]']
 )

 zero_padding2d_28 (ZeroPadding  (None, 4, 4, 256)   0           ['stage4_unit1_relu1[0][0]']
 2D)

 stage4_unit1_conv1 (Conv2D)    (None, 1, 1, 512)    1179648     ['zero_padding2d_28[0][0]']

 stage4_unit1_bn2 (BatchNormali  (None, 1, 1, 512)   2048        ['stage4_unit1_conv1[0][0]']
 zation)

 stage4_unit1_relu2 (Activation  (None, 1, 1, 512)   0           ['stage4_unit1_bn2[0][0]']
 )

 zero_padding2d_29 (ZeroPadding  (None, 3, 3, 512)   0           ['stage4_unit1_relu2[0][0]']
 2D)

 stage4_unit1_conv2 (Conv2D)    (None, 1, 1, 512)    2359296     ['zero_padding2d_29[0][0]']

 stage4_unit1_sc (Conv2D)       (None, 1, 1, 512)    131072      ['stage4_unit1_relu1[0][0]']

 add_13 (Add)                   (None, 1, 1, 512)    0           ['stage4_unit1_conv2[0][0]',
                                                                  'stage4_unit1_sc[0][0]']

 stage4_unit2_bn1 (BatchNormali  (None, 1, 1, 512)   2048        ['add_13[0][0]']
 zation)

 stage4_unit2_relu1 (Activation  (None, 1, 1, 512)   0           ['stage4_unit2_bn1[0][0]']
 )

 zero_padding2d_30 (ZeroPadding  (None, 3, 3, 512)   0           ['stage4_unit2_relu1[0][0]']
 2D)

 stage4_unit2_conv1 (Conv2D)    (None, 1, 1, 512)    2359296     ['zero_padding2d_30[0][0]']

 stage4_unit2_bn2 (BatchNormali  (None, 1, 1, 512)   2048        ['stage4_unit2_conv1[0][0]']
 zation)

 stage4_unit2_relu2 (Activation  (None, 1, 1, 512)   0           ['stage4_unit2_bn2[0][0]']
 )

 zero_padding2d_31 (ZeroPadding  (None, 3, 3, 512)   0           ['stage4_unit2_relu2[0][0]']
 2D)

 stage4_unit2_conv2 (Conv2D)    (None, 1, 1, 512)    2359296     ['zero_padding2d_31[0][0]']

 add_14 (Add)                   (None, 1, 1, 512)    0           ['stage4_unit2_conv2[0][0]',
                                                                  'add_13[0][0]']

 stage4_unit3_bn1 (BatchNormali  (None, 1, 1, 512)   2048        ['add_14[0][0]']
 zation)

 stage4_unit3_relu1 (Activation  (None, 1, 1, 512)   0           ['stage4_unit3_bn1[0][0]']
 )

 zero_padding2d_32 (ZeroPadding  (None, 3, 3, 512)   0           ['stage4_unit3_relu1[0][0]']
 2D)

 stage4_unit3_conv1 (Conv2D)    (None, 1, 1, 512)    2359296     ['zero_padding2d_32[0][0]']

 stage4_unit3_bn2 (BatchNormali  (None, 1, 1, 512)   2048        ['stage4_unit3_conv1[0][0]']
 zation)

 stage4_unit3_relu2 (Activation  (None, 1, 1, 512)   0           ['stage4_unit3_bn2[0][0]']
 )

 zero_padding2d_33 (ZeroPadding  (None, 3, 3, 512)   0           ['stage4_unit3_relu2[0][0]']
 2D)

 stage4_unit3_conv2 (Conv2D)    (None, 1, 1, 512)    2359296     ['zero_padding2d_33[0][0]']

 add_15 (Add)                   (None, 1, 1, 512)    0           ['stage4_unit3_conv2[0][0]',
                                                                  'add_14[0][0]']

 bn1 (BatchNormalization)       (None, 1, 1, 512)    2048        ['add_15[0][0]']

 relu1 (Activation)             (None, 1, 1, 512)    0           ['bn1[0][0]']

 decoder_stage0_upsampling (UpS  (None, 2, 2, 512)   0           ['relu1[0][0]']
 ampling2D)

 decoder_stage0_concat (Concate  (None, 2, 2, 768)   0           ['decoder_stage0_upsampling[0][0]
 nate)                                                           ',
                                                                  'stage4_unit1_relu1[0][0]']

 decoder_stage0a_conv (Conv2D)  (None, 2, 2, 256)    1769472     ['decoder_stage0_concat[0][0]']

 decoder_stage0a_bn (BatchNorma  (None, 2, 2, 256)   1024        ['decoder_stage0a_conv[0][0]']
 lization)

 decoder_stage0a_relu (Activati  (None, 2, 2, 256)   0           ['decoder_stage0a_bn[0][0]']
 on)

 decoder_stage0b_conv (Conv2D)  (None, 2, 2, 256)    589824      ['decoder_stage0a_relu[0][0]']

 decoder_stage0b_bn (BatchNorma  (None, 2, 2, 256)   1024        ['decoder_stage0b_conv[0][0]']
 lization)

 decoder_stage0b_relu (Activati  (None, 2, 2, 256)   0           ['decoder_stage0b_bn[0][0]']
 on)

 decoder_stage1_upsampling (UpS  (None, 4, 4, 256)   0           ['decoder_stage0b_relu[0][0]']
 ampling2D)

 decoder_stage1_concat (Concate  (None, 4, 4, 384)   0           ['decoder_stage1_upsampling[0][0]
 nate)                                                           ',
                                                                  'stage3_unit1_relu1[0][0]']

 decoder_stage1a_conv (Conv2D)  (None, 4, 4, 128)    442368      ['decoder_stage1_concat[0][0]']

 decoder_stage1a_bn (BatchNorma  (None, 4, 4, 128)   512         ['decoder_stage1a_conv[0][0]']
 lization)

 decoder_stage1a_relu (Activati  (None, 4, 4, 128)   0           ['decoder_stage1a_bn[0][0]']
 on)

 decoder_stage1b_conv (Conv2D)  (None, 4, 4, 128)    147456      ['decoder_stage1a_relu[0][0]']

 decoder_stage1b_bn (BatchNorma  (None, 4, 4, 128)   512         ['decoder_stage1b_conv[0][0]']
 lization)

 decoder_stage1b_relu (Activati  (None, 4, 4, 128)   0           ['decoder_stage1b_bn[0][0]']
 on)

 decoder_stage2_upsampling (UpS  (None, 8, 8, 128)   0           ['decoder_stage1b_relu[0][0]']
 ampling2D)

 decoder_stage2_concat (Concate  (None, 8, 8, 192)   0           ['decoder_stage2_upsampling[0][0]
 nate)                                                           ',
                                                                  'stage2_unit1_relu1[0][0]']

 decoder_stage2a_conv (Conv2D)  (None, 8, 8, 64)     110592      ['decoder_stage2_concat[0][0]']

 decoder_stage2a_bn (BatchNorma  (None, 8, 8, 64)    256         ['decoder_stage2a_conv[0][0]']
 lization)

 decoder_stage2a_relu (Activati  (None, 8, 8, 64)    0           ['decoder_stage2a_bn[0][0]']
 on)

 decoder_stage2b_conv (Conv2D)  (None, 8, 8, 64)     36864       ['decoder_stage2a_relu[0][0]']

 decoder_stage2b_bn (BatchNorma  (None, 8, 8, 64)    256         ['decoder_stage2b_conv[0][0]']
 lization)

 decoder_stage2b_relu (Activati  (None, 8, 8, 64)    0           ['decoder_stage2b_bn[0][0]']
 on)

 decoder_stage3_upsampling (UpS  (None, 16, 16, 64)  0           ['decoder_stage2b_relu[0][0]']
 ampling2D)

 decoder_stage3_concat (Concate  (None, 16, 16, 128)  0          ['decoder_stage3_upsampling[0][0]
 nate)                                                           ',
                                                                  'relu0[0][0]']

 decoder_stage3a_conv (Conv2D)  (None, 16, 16, 32)   36864       ['decoder_stage3_concat[0][0]']

 decoder_stage3a_bn (BatchNorma  (None, 16, 16, 32)  128         ['decoder_stage3a_conv[0][0]']
 lization)

 decoder_stage3a_relu (Activati  (None, 16, 16, 32)  0           ['decoder_stage3a_bn[0][0]']
 on)

 decoder_stage3b_conv (Conv2D)  (None, 16, 16, 32)   9216        ['decoder_stage3a_relu[0][0]']

 decoder_stage3b_bn (BatchNorma  (None, 16, 16, 32)  128         ['decoder_stage3b_conv[0][0]']
 lization)

 decoder_stage3b_relu (Activati  (None, 16, 16, 32)  0           ['decoder_stage3b_bn[0][0]']
 on)

 decoder_stage4_upsampling (UpS  (None, 32, 32, 32)  0           ['decoder_stage3b_relu[0][0]']
 ampling2D)

 decoder_stage4a_conv (Conv2D)  (None, 32, 32, 16)   4608        ['decoder_stage4_upsampling[0][0]
                                                                 ']

 decoder_stage4a_bn (BatchNorma  (None, 32, 32, 16)  64          ['decoder_stage4a_conv[0][0]']
 lization)

 decoder_stage4a_relu (Activati  (None, 32, 32, 16)  0           ['decoder_stage4a_bn[0][0]']
 on)

 decoder_stage4b_conv (Conv2D)  (None, 32, 32, 16)   2304        ['decoder_stage4a_relu[0][0]']

 decoder_stage4b_bn (BatchNorma  (None, 32, 32, 16)  64          ['decoder_stage4b_conv[0][0]']
 lization)

 decoder_stage4b_relu (Activati  (None, 32, 32, 16)  0           ['decoder_stage4b_bn[0][0]']
 on)

 final_conv (Conv2D)            (None, 32, 32, 3)    435         ['decoder_stage4b_relu[0][0]']

 sigmoid (Activation)           (None, 32, 32, 3)    0           ['final_conv[0][0]']

==================================================================================================
Total params: 24,456,444
Trainable params: 24,439,094
Non-trainable params: 17,350
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
model load: F:\models\checkpoint\test_tf_U-net\TF_DataSets_01.h5
Press Any Key!
Epoch 1/5
2022-10-15 19:47:17.222480: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:384] Loaded cuDNN version 8100
1/1 [==============================] - 14s 14s/step - loss: 0.4313 - root_mean_squared_error: 0.6568
```

Comment: oh ok nice! this fix all the 'none' I had in my summary but I still have the same error on shape which now is (None, 256, 256, 3) on an input with incompatible shape (None, 256, 256, 1). Why?

Comment: p.s. setting input_shape=(256, 256, 1) gives me:
ValueError: Cannot assign value to variable ' bn_data/beta:0': Shape mismatch.The variable shape (1,), and the assigned value shape (3,) are incompatible. @Jirayu Kaewprateep